# Passing directly an array initializer to a method parameter doesn't work

Tags: java, arrays

```
package arraypkg;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main
{
    private static void foo(Object o[])
    {
        System.out.printf("%s", Arrays.toString(o));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
       Object []o=new Object[]{1,2,3,4,5};
       foo(o);                     //Passing an array of objects to the foo() method.

       foo(new Object[]{6,7,8,9}); //This is valid as obvious.

       Object[] o1 = {1, 2};      //This is also fine.
       foo(o1);

       foo({1,2});               //This looks something similar to the preceding one. This is however wrong and doesn't compile - not a statement.
    }
}
```

In the preceding code snippet all the expressions except the last one are compiled and run fine. Although the last statement which looks something similar to its immediate statement, the compiler issues a compile-time error - illegal start of expression - not a statement. Why?

Comment: it's a shortcoming of the language. hopefully they'll fix it someday

Comment: No it's not a shortcoming of the language.  It's a consequence of how method binding works.  Method binding requires the types of the arguments/parameters to be known from the invocation (the call site) and it is therefore impossible to try and infer the array type from the concrete signture of the bound method, because that hasn't been determined yet and cannot be determined without knowing the arguments/parameters types.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
foo({1,2});
```

{1, 2} this kind of array initialization only work at the place you are declaring an array.. At other places, you have to create it using `new` keyword..

That is why: -

```
Object[] obj = {1, 2};
```

Was fine..
This is because, the type of array, is implied by the type of `reference` we use on LHS.. But, while we use it somewhere else, Compiler cannot find out the type (Like in your case)..

Try using : -

```
  foo(new Object[]{1,2});
```

Comment: I think OP is more interested in explanation, specifically because `Object[] o1 = {1, 2};` worked.

Comment: I have already looked into [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/arrays.html#10.6) - "*An array initializer may be specified in a declaration, or as part of an array creation expression [(§15.10)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/expressions.html#46168), creating an array and providing some initial values*" but didn't find more details. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

`foo({1,2});`       doesn't tell what type of array it is. So, compiler fails to understand the syntax. All other declarations specify type of array.

Comment: @PratyushVerma: Yes, that is correct. But, as Tiny commented on Rohit answer, that syntax is valid only as part of an array creation expression. Outside of it, jvm can't understand what it is.

Answer (score 1):

`foo({1,2});` is NOT an Array.

And as your `foo()`  method takes an **array type parameter**, this fails.