# How to pass a function an array literal?

Tags: java, arrays

How do I pass a array without making it a seperate variable? For example I know this works:

```
class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String[] arbitraryStrings={"foo"};
        takesStringArray(arbitraryStrings);
    }
    public static void takesStringArray(String[] argument){
        System.out.println(argument);
    }
}
```

But I dont want to make the array a variable as it is only used here. Is there any way to do something like this:

```
class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        takesStringArray({"foo"});
    }
    public static void takesStringArray(String[] argument){
        System.out.println(argument);
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing directly an array initializer to a method parameter doesn't work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12805535/passing-directly-an-array-initializer-to-a-method-parameter-doesnt-work)

Comment: Consider taking a look at Groovy: http://groovy.codehaus.org/.

In Groovy, you can just define list literals anywhere you like.  it's sweet!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`{"foo"}` doens't tell Java anything about what type of array you are trying to create...

Instead, try something like...

```
takesStringArray(new String[] {"foo"});
```

Answer (score 2):

You are able to create an array with `new`, and without **A new variable**

The correct syntax you are expecting is,

```
  takesStringArray(new String[]{"foo"});
```

Seems, you are just started with `arrays`.There are many other syntax's to declare an `array`.

- [How do I declare and initialize an array in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200621/how-to-declare-an-array-in-java)

Answer (score 2):

```
class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        takesStringArray(new String[]{"foo"});
    }

    public static void takesStringArray(String[] argument) {
        System.out.println(argument);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use `in-line` array declaration

try

```
takesStringArray(new String[]{"foo"});
```

Answer (score 0):

u may try [VarArgs](http://java-demos.blogspot.in/2012/12/java-varargs-tutorial.html):

```
class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        takesStringArray("foo", "bar");
    }
    public static void takesStringArray(String... argument){
        System.out.println(argument);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use varargs:

```
class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        takesStringArray("foo");
    }

    public static void takesStringArray(String... argument) {
        System.out.println(argument);
    }  
}
```