# integer array in a collection

Tags: java, arrays, collections

I would like to have a collection that holds arrays of integers.

```
List<int[]> pairs = new ArrayList<>();
```

in order to add there an element I have to:

```
int[] newArray = {1, 2};
pairs.add(newArray);
```

Can someone explain my why the below does not work:

```
 pairs.add({1,2});
```

is there any other way to add {1,2} to pairs without creating newArray object?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing directly an array initializer to a method parameter doesn't work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12805535/passing-directly-an-array-initializer-to-a-method-parameter-doesnt-work) (should have looked for duplicates before answering, but at least the answer here quotes the spec. in the answer).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most of the time, you'll need to do `new int[] { 1, 2 }`:

```
pairs.add( new int[] {1,2} );
```

The only place that you can avoid the `new int[]` is when you're declaring a variable of type `int[]`, as you've done with `int[] newArray = {1, 2};`. It's just a limitation of the language design.  In particular, you can read [10.6. Array Initializers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.6) in the specification, which states that:

> An array initializer may be specified in a declaration (§8.3, §9.3,
>   §14.4), or as part of an array creation expression (§15.10), to create
>   an array and provide some initial values.

The important thing to take away from that is that `{ 1, 2 }`, is an array initializer, and you can use it in a declaration (`int[] newArray = {1, 2};`), or in an array creation expression (`new int[] { 1, 2 }`);  you can't use it on its own.

Answer (score 1):

You got the syntax slightly wrong.
Try this: `pairs.add(new int[]{1,2});`